# Start Python server in Docker, access from localhost

Tags: python, macos, docker

I have a Docker container with a few Python script inside. One of these script starts up an HTTP server. I want to be able to access this server from `localhost` on my host machine (macOS).

My run command is as follows:

```
docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:7850:80 -v ~/path/to/scripts:/src my-container
```

Than, I manually start the Python script to get the server running. The Python script starts the HTTP server on `127.0.0.1:80`.

On my host machine, I try `curl 127.0.0.1:7850 -d '{}'`, but the server is not returning what it should. Also, the Python script itself should print all received JSON data, but does not print anything.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: you should run the server inside the container with `0.0.0.0` IP address. And when you run the docker just use `-p` flag i.e `-p "<port_on_localhost>:<port_on_docker>"`. Now you can access your server with `localhost:<port_on_localhost>`

Comment: @ArpitGoyal This works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: @JNevens - Could you please share your server and client code?